# Python extended Euclidean algortihm + inverse modulo

Tags: python, reinventing-the-wheel, mathematics, cryptography

I programmed the extended Euclidean algorithm together with the inverse modulo because I am making an RSA system from scratch. Any feedback regarding efficiency etc. is welcome :)

```
    def ext_gcd(a, b):

        a0, a1 = a, b
        x0, x1 = 1, 0
        y0, y1 = 0, 1

        while a1 != 0:
            q = a0//a1
            r, s, t = a1, x1, y1
            a1 = a0 % a1
            x1 = x0 - q*x1
            y1 = y0 - q*y1
            a0, x0, y0 = r, s, t

        return x0, y0, a0

    def inverse_mod(a, mod):
        va, y0, a0 = Math.ext_gcd(a, mod)
        return va % mod
```

Comment: No... the answer given there isn't very time efficient...

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ  You likely know this but [duplicates are different on CR](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/a/5704/120114)

Comment: I'm voting to repoen because while both posts involve the Euclidean algorithm this one also mentions inverse modulo. For context, see meta posts like [this](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/a/5704/120114) and [this](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/a/5896/120114)

Comment: While the issues I'd raise with both snippets overlap, I think them sufficiently different to not qualify as duplicates.

Comment: I also thought that this shouldn't be marked as duplicate... yes me and the other guy have both the same mathematical algorithm but mine is a little bit different and the answers given there... well the one answer at the moment uses the most time inefficient approach I have ever seen and I was asking also for feedback for time efficiency. I would appreciate a reopen.

Answer (score 2):

Give your variables more meaningful names reflecting their role in the algorithm.

Comment: I'm getting some dejavu here...

Comment: @Peilonrayz Sure, me too ....